# Optimize SQL to find sports (basketball) lineups

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to setup a SQL database to record the 3 person lineups that have occurred in the game. The structure I have now is:

### Player

playerID
playerName

### Lineup

lineupID

### Lineup_players

lineupID (foreign key)
playerID (foreign key)

I want to find a quick way to check whether a particular set of 3 players are already part of a lineup. Suppose I want to find a lineup with players A,B,C, the solution I can think of is something like:

```
SELECT t1.lineupID
FROM (SELECT lineupID FROM Lineup_players WHERE playerID=A) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT lineupID FROM Lineup_players WHERE playerID=B) t2 ON t1.lineupID = t2.lineupID
INNER JOIN (SELECT lineupID FROM Lineup_players WHERE playerID=C) t3 ON t1.lineupID = t3.lineupID
```

I feel that this is a clumsy solution. Is there a faster query using the same tables, or is there a better way to store the data?

Also, if I have players A,B,C,D,E in my lineup, is there a fast way of finding all lineups with any 3 of these players without checking all 20 combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking something like this?

```
select
  lineupid,
  count(*)
from
  Lineup_players
where
  playerid in (A,B,C,D,E)
group by
  lineupid
having
  count(*) >= 3
```

This will list you the lineups that have 3 or more of the listed ids.

Comment: it certainly works. it uses the dreaded "in clause", kinda never use them for code reviews/interviews. that said don't anyone vote for mine. i am anti-votes   :>

Comment: Thanks, guys! What's the problem with an 'in clause'? Sorry if this is a basic question...

Comment: Well the in clause basically requires dynamic SQL, if you're going to pass different number of values from the client, but of course you can replace that with any search criteria you need to have.